# Facebook create Open Graph object with custom field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, custom-fields

I have an object type created, lets call it "foo". This one inherits from "object" but has an additional attribute "fooattribute". My Application runs under lets say "fooapplication"

When I set this attribute to optional I can create an app owned object using the Graph API directly and all works.

I call the url: `app/objects/fooapplication:foo`
With the parameter: `object:{"type":"fooapplication:spot","title":"test","description":"","image":"someimage-url","fooapplication:fooattribute":"Test"}`

But a soon as i set the attribute fooattribute to required, i get an error on creating objects:

`Object Missing a Required Value: Object at URL '' of type 'fooapplication:foo' is invalid because a required property 'fooapplication:fooattribute' of type 'string' was not provided."`

Can anyone help me and tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

I use an application authentification token to access my app. And the namespace and the attribute names have been exchanged ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I was actually trying to find answer to this very question.  I came across this SO post that helped me: [Facebook create Open Graph object with custom field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190252/facebook-create-open-graph-object-with-custom-field)

You need to pack your custom attributes into an object named data in the json you're sending to the open graph.  So something like this:

```
{
  "type":"fooapplication:spot",
  "title":"test",
  "description":"",
  "image":"someimage-url",
  "data":{
    fooattribute":"Test"
  }
}
```

Full disclosure I was doing this via the iOS SDK but the process seems to be the same. Hope this helps.